# how to show tooltip in jqgrid edit/add form buttons

Tags: jqgrid

I tried

```
      grid.navGrid("#grid_toppager",{},
    {
            bSubmit: 'Submit',
            editCaption: 'Edit',
       title: 'Save changes (Ctrl+S)' } );
```

but Save changes (Ctrl+S) tooltip does not appear if mouse is over Submit button. how to show tooltip in edit and add form submit buttons ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no `title` option of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator) method. There are only options like `edittitle` or `addtitle` which are not what you need.

What you need is to set `title` attribute on the "Submit" button which you have to do directly inside of `beforeShowForm` for example. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SaveFormByKeydown.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If u want to add tooltip on your custom jqgrid buttons then just add title .

```
.navButtonAdd('#discPgr',{ title:"Add Discount" });
```